# BiBTeX in WinEdt

Tags: bibtex, winedt

I have a problem. Using WinEdt try to make my bibliography with the bibtex file. But get the following message

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99c (MiKTeX 2.8)
The top-level auxiliary file: report_q_cdc11.aux
The style file: unsrt.bst
I couldn't open database file biblio/1755988.bib
---line 62 of file report_q_cdc11.aux
: \bibdata{biblio/1755988
:                        }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file report_q_cdc11.aux
(There were 2 error messages)
```

Could you please tell me, what can be wrong? This bibtex file I just downloaded from web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this test file and also controll that your bibfile is readable and in the correct subdirectory. What happens?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblio/1755988}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Command Line:   bibtex.exe "test"
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99c (MiKTeX 2.8)
The top-level auxiliary file: test.aux
The style file: plain.bst
I couldn't open database file biblio/1755988.bib
---line 4 of file test.aux
 : \bibdata{biblio/1755988
 :                        }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file test.aux
(There were 2 error messages)

Comment: @Gortaur please copy the bib file into your document directory and use `\bibliography{1755988}`. Same problem?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. It even writes "I couldn't open database file biblio/1755988.bib" though I changed the syntax in accordance to your advise. Maybe I need to change some preferences in WinEdt (it's the first time I try to use BiBTeX with WinEdt).

Comment: @Gortaur, sure because you didn't run the document twice. You can also delete the `*.aux` file to be sure, that not the old bib filename is read.

Comment: Thanks, now it works only with \nocite{*}. What is it?

Comment: @Gortaur: I have no idea how a path must be given under windows, but maybe that you have to use it this way: `\bibliography{biblio\1755988}` when the bib is in a subdirectory

Comment: @Herbert, it works now properly. But I have to use \nocite{*} - I do not know what is it. Maybe it's becuase I did not make any cites insede the paper yet?

Comment: @Gortaur: `\nocite{*}` is only a command to include _all_ of the bibliography entries. You should have at least _one_ `\cite{..}` in your document to have the `\bibliography` command wirking.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I have already realized it. The question seems to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your bibliography file (`1755988.bib`) is either misspelled, or missing. Check whether it is in the `biblio` folder in the directory where you are compiling the `.tex` file.

You need to hunt the

```
\bibliography{biblio/1755988}
```

line in your source code, and see whether it corresponds to the `.bib` file you're trying to use.

Comment: I wrote \bibliography{biblio/1755988} rather then \bibliography{biblio/1755988.bib} - but when I fixed ".bib" the situation has not changed. The file is in the same folder.

Comment: @Gortaur: You mean the `1755988.bib` file is in the `biblio` folder? If yes, then you'll need to write a short minimum example that illustrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As a last remedy, you can run [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx). Set the variable MIKTEX_TRACE, e.g.

```
Set MIKTEX_TRACE=access,curl,error,process,config,env,filesearch,files,core,tempfile
```

from a command prompt and run bibtex on your aux file. Investigate the trace log in the  DebugView window. This will certainly locate what the problem is caused by. Note that WinEdt 6 makes it possible to set MIKTEX_TRACE through winEdt menu: Options | Execution Modes | Variable.